# Convert modal to IHierarchicalEnumerable

Tags: c#

I am having some class like

```
public class Employee
{
    public List<Employee> ChildOrg{get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;};
    public string id{get; set;};
    public string parentid{get; set;};
}
```

Now in project I am having the object of Employee that contains the actual hierarchy to display in TreeView.

Now to give this object TreeView i need to give IHierarchicalEnumarable type reference.

**So how can i convert my Modal to IHierarchicalEnumrable and give it to TreeView?**

I already used following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19639/Implementing-IHierarchy-Support-Into-Your-Custom-C

**In above link i am specially confused about "GetChildern" and "GetParent" method i am unable to understand how it can fit in my requirement where i am already having hierarchy.**

I am unable to understand please help me to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out how I can use `IHierarchicalEnumerable`.

Please check out following. Modified my model class like this:

```
public class Employee : IHierarchyData
{
    public EmployeeCollection ChildOrg { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

    public IHierarchicalEnumerable GetChildren()
    {
        return ChildOrg as IHierarchicalEnumerable;
    }

    public System.Web.UI.IHierarchyData GetParent()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return ((this.ChildOrg != null) && (this.ChildOrg.Count > 0)); }
    }

    public object Item
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get { return this.id; }
    }

    public string Type
    {
        get { return this.GetType().ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Added new class as follows:

```
public class EmployeeCollection : List<Employee>, IHierarchicalEnumerable
{
    public IHierarchyData GetHierarchyData(object enumeratedItem)
    {
        return enumeratedItem as IHierarchyData;
    }
}
```

And used recursive function to create hierarchy.